# Lenovo IdeaPad U410 - multitouch support

Tags: lenovo, touchegg

For the last 3 month I've been trying to make touchegg to support more then 2 finger gestures with my Lenovo IdeaPad u410.
I tried to run touchegg on: Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 12.10, Ubuntu Gnome remix 12.04 and Ubuntu Gnome remix 12.10.
Now I'm running Ubuntu Gnome remix 12.10 (Because I understood that 3 fingers gestures might be reserved in Unity.)

After disabling synclient by this commands:

```
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
synclient ClickFinger2=0
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
```

I only manage to enable 2 fingers gestures so far.

Lately I've discovered that geistest shows me this following output:

```
Device 45280 added
attr "device name" = "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
attr "device id" = 45280
attr "device touches" = 2
attr "direct touch" = false
attr "independent touch" = false
attr "device X minimum" = 1472.000000
attr "device X maximum" = 5664.000000
attr "device X resolution" = 42000.000000
attr "device Y minimum" = 1408.000000
attr "device Y maximum" = 4682.000000
attr "device Y resolution" = 52000.000000
```

Is that mean that my Synaptics driver support only 2 fingers?!?!
If so how can it be? Under windows I do have more then 2 finger gestures...

Please if any one can help my... this issue driving my crazy =.

Thx,

Gal.

Answer (score 0):

To determine what your trackpad is supporting you can use the following:

```
xinput -list
xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" | grep Capabilities
```

Replace the string with the model of your trackpad. Compare the output with the following:

> From left to right, this shows:
>
> - (1) device has a physical left button
> - (0) device does not have a physical middle button
> - (1) device has a physical right button
> - (0) device does not support two-finger detection
> - (0) device does not support three-finger detection
> - (1) device can configure vertical resolution
> - (1) device can configure horizontal resolution

Taken from [Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Using_xinput_to_determine_touchpad_capabilities)